# Вместо ответа появляется "[object HTMLParagraphElement][object HTMLParagraphElement]"

Tags: javascript, калькулятор

Я новичок, создаю простой калькулятор.

Есть кнопка `=`, при нажатии на которую срабатывает функция `rez()`.

```
<button onclick="rez()">=</button>
```

Сама функция выглядит так:

```
function rez(){
  var num1, num2, znak, result;

    num1 = document.getElementById("out");
    num2 = document.getElementById("out2");
    znak = document.getElementById("out1");
    result = num1 + num2;
    stroka = document.getElementById("out3");

    stroka.innerHTML += result;

}
```

И когда я нажимаю знак `=`, вместо того, чтобы писать ответ, появляется вот такая строка:

```
[object HTMLParagraphElement][object HTMLParagraphElement]
```

Пожалуйста, помогите решить!!! Уже 2 часа не могу решение найти!

Напишите ответ простым языком, если это возможно, а то я не сильно в этом разбираюсь))

Comment: `result = +num1.innerHTML + +num2.innerHTML;`

Comment: И будьте так добры, на будущее НИКОГДА не писать транслитом название переменных, таких как `znak` - приучите себя писать строго на английском языке. Не беда, если не знаете английского, переводчики сейчас повсюду!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function rez(){
    var num1, num2, znak, result;

    num1 = +document.getElementById("out").textContent;
    num2 = +document.getElementById("out2").textContent;
    znak = document.getElementById("out1").textContent;
    result = num1 + num2;
    stroka = document.getElementById("out3");
    stroka.innerHTML += result;
}
```

Comment: СПАСИБО!!!! А в чём проблема то моя была?

Comment: Проблема была в том, что вы пытались взять объект HTML заметки, вместо контента внутри тэга.

Answer (score 2):

Функция [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) возвращает html элемент.

При сложении `result = num1 + num2;` выбранные элементы приводятся к строке, и так как это параграфы получилось `[object HTMLParagraphElement][object HTMLParagraphElement]`

для решения нужно взять содержимое этих элементов: [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), либо [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) и привести к числам, например используя функцию [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

В итоге получится:

```
num1 = Number(document.getElementById("out").innerHTML);
num2 = Number(document.getElementById("out2").innerHTML);
```

Comment: Спасибо) Теперь я понял в чём проблема! Пойду дальше делать свой первый калькулятор)

Answer (score 0):

```
function rez(){
  var num1, num2, znak, result, stroka;

    num1 = document.getElementById("out");
    num2 = document.getElementById("out2");
    znak = document.getElementById("out1");
    result = num1 + num2;
    stroka = document.getElementById("out3");

    stroka.innerHTML += result;

}
```

Ты не сделал var для stroka

Comment: `var` необязательно :)

Comment: почему ? он же 
function rez(){
  var num1, num2, znak, result;

    num1 = document.getElementById("out");
    num2 = document.getElementById("out2");
    znak = document.getElementById("out1");
    result = num1 + num2;
    stroka = document.getElementById("out3");

    stroka.innerHTML += result;

}

Comment: Что почему? ...