# Помогите решить проблему с JavaScript

Tags: javascript

У меня проблема! Я делаю калькулятор на js. У меня есть переменная d, по умолчанию она равна 2. Когда пользователь нажимает на какой либо знак, например на "+", значение переменной меняется на 3. 
И так по сути прога должна определять какой знак поставил пользователь (знаю, это глупо, но ничего лучше придумать не смог, так как я новичок) и вычислять. 
В итоге я сделал функцию rez, которая срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку "равно".
Но почему то "if" работает странно, и калькулятор постоянно складывает, вне зависимости он того, какой знак я ставлю! В чём причина???

```
function rez(){
var num1, num2, znak, result, stroka;

if (d=3){
num1 = +document.getElementById("out").textContent;
num2 = +document.getElementById("out2").textContent;
znak = document.getElementById("out1").textContent;
result = num1 + num2;
stroka = document.getElementById("out3");
stroka.innerHTML = result;
}
else if(d=4){
num1 = +document.getElementById("out").textContent;
num2 = +document.getElementById("out2").textContent;
znak = document.getElementById("out1").textContent;
result = num1 - num2;
stroka = document.getElementById("out3");
stroka.innerHTML = result;  
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cравнение - двойной знак "равно":

```
if (d == 3) {
  ...
} else if (d == 4) {
  ...
}
```

---

Вы забыли нажать на знак "галочка" возле моего :) ответа вот здесь:

[Вместо ответа появляется "[object HTMLParagraphElement][object HTMLParagraphElement]"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/896053/%D0%92%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-object-htmlparagraphelementobject-htmlparagraphelem)

---

P.S. Представьте, что все будут давать своим вопросам подобные заголовки.

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз! Галочку поставил)

Comment: @АндрейСеменченко Пожалуйста. Успехов!